# not able to move files using rename command in sftp

Tags: shell, unix, sftp

I have one sftp script which first moves all the .seq files to temp folder then uses mget command and then deletes them.. below  is the sftp portion of the script.

```
sshpass -p red32hat sftp $userID@$serverIP <<EOF
cd /root/perl
rename *.seq /root/perl/temp/*.seq
cd ./temp
mget *.seq
rm *seq
bye
EOF
```

now problem I am facing with rename command while moving the files...coz one file we can move by using below command.

```
rename geetika.seq /root/perl/temp/geetika.seq
```

but while moving all the seq files its is not allowing to run the below command and throwing the error. File "/root/perl/temp/*.seq" not found.

```
rename *.seq /root/perl/temp/*.seq
```

also I didn't find any way to take one file at a time and rename it in sftp. Please help if any one way is possible (all files at a time or one by one...)

Comment: Change: "rename \*.seq /root/perl/temp/\*.seq" to "rename \*.seq /root/perl/temp/"

Comment: it isn't taking it...throwing error..."Couldn't rename file "/root/perl/*.seq" to "/root/perl/temp": No such file or directory"

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
rename *.seq /root/perl/temp/*.seq
```

to

```
!mv /root/perl/*.seq /root/perl/temp/
```

From the help in sftp:

> !command - Execute 'command' in local
>   shell

Comment: hi..I tried it but its giving me this error..."mv: accessing `/root/perl/temp': Permission denied"   I even tried to give 777 permission to temp directory but got the same error...please help...thanks

Comment: Can you perform the command "mv /root/perl/\*.seq /root/perl/temp/" in a regular terminal without using sftp?